# Error: In C, got the error "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" in a struct pointer

Tags: c, pointers, header, struct, dereference

**Hello Everybody!**

I got the following error, while trying to test a code for the game Clever Frog:
**error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type**

**The 'full code' is at pastebin.com - [here](http://pastebin.com/ZbudbbVE)** (won't expire). But I think that with the explanation below, anybody can understands. Note: I haven't implemented yet the function that will erase the allocated memory and other things.

I have a struct defined in a 1.c file:

```
#include "1.h"
...
struct test {
   int a;
   };
...
```

I have a 1.h wicth have the typedef using it:

```
...
typedef struct test testT;
...
```

Then I have a function that has a parameter in it depending on testT, wich is in 2.c:

```
...
void funcTest(testT **t, int *size, ..){
   /* another function that creates mem.space/alocate memory based enter code here`on the need of size above */
   createMem(t,*size); /* void createMem(testT **t, int size); */

   t[0]->a = 0; /*ERROR HERE*/
   /* ... more code ... */
}
...
```

The 2.h file is like this:

```
...
void funcTest(testT **t, int *size, ..);
...
```

I will pass a **testT *var** as the way below, at the main programam:

```
...
testT *varTest; int size;

funcTest(&varTest, &size);
...
```

The bizarre thing is that the code compile when I use **struct test** at 1.h file (removing *struct test* from 1.c - which is wrong). But, when running the compiled program, exactly where the error occurs is the place of *t[0]->a*.

I already tried 'everything' but nothing worked :( I have faith that is something very stupid, so if anybody knows something, please tell me :D
Thanks!

Comment: **EDIT**
"The bizarre thing is that the code compile when I use struct test at 1.h file (removing struct test from 1.c - which is wrong). But, when running the compiled program, exactly where the error occurs is the place of t[0]->a."

The error is "segmentation fault".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you try to access the `a` member of the `t[0]` struct the compiler needs to know how this struct looks like (for example to see if there even is any `a` member in it). Since you didn't put the `struct test` type definition anywhere where the compiler can see it when compiling `2.c`, you get an error. The compiler doesn't know what a `struct test` contains.

If you put the definition of the `struct test` in `1.h`, the compiler sees how that type looks like and can use the struct members.

Just put the complete type definition in `1.h`, that's where it's supposed to be.

Comment: About the correct place of `struct test` I thugh that it was in *.c and `typedef` in *.h Uhn.. When I do this, I get `segmentation fault` at the position of `t[0]->a = 0`. _I should have_ said that in place od `0`, it will get a value from a input from user; here: http://pastebin.com/ZbudbbVE

Comment: @Shuryon: The correct place is in the *.h. About the segmentation fault: probably this means that `createMem` didn't actually set t[0] to point to something useful.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere you have a preprocessed file that has

```
typedef struct test testT;
```

Which doesn't include

```
struct test {
   int a;
};
```

Preprocessing inlines all the #includes directives.  As long as you were only using a testT pointer, the compiler would have known to "allocate a pointer's worth of memory" and the compilation would have progressed further than expected.

When you actually try to use that pointer to dereference something, the compiler would then realize it NEEDED the full definition of "struct test" and you would get the error displayed.

Comment: You meand I need to include the correct *.h, right? But it is (I think), so I don't know what to do. Take a look: http://pastebin.com/ZbudbbVE

Answer (score 1):

If you want the struct to be usable both in 1.c and 2.c, it must be defined in a header file that is visible to both. I don't know why you say that this is "wrong", it's common practice and AFAIK there is no other way around that directly.

If it's only defined in 1.c, then the compiler has no idea if `struct test` has a member named "a" when processing 2.c.

Another option is to just keep the forward declaration as you have now, but also include accessor/mutator functions in the header. Then 2.c does not have to know about the "internals" of `struct test`, but can act on it. This is also very common in C APIs.

(You could also define the struct identically both in 1.c and 2.c but that's a **very** bad idea.)

Comment: `"1.h"` does not contain a definition of `struct test`. It only says "there is a struct test somewhere" and defines another name for that type. With just that, when looking at `"2.c"`, the compiler does not know what `struct test` actually is, so it can only do things with it that don't require any knowledge of the struct (like handling pointers to it). `struct test` is an "opaque type" at this point. You might want to search for that term to find more information.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of `struct Test` is only visible inside the file 1.c. The code `t[0]->a` doesn't see that this struct has a member named `a`. The types shared between several compile units shuld be defined in a header!

You should know that C/C++ compiles each .c file separately, so it has no way to know that the structure is defined in some other .c file.

You should perhaps do the following:

(1.h)

```
struct test {
    int a;
};
...
```

(1.c)

```
#include "1.h"
...
```

(2.c)

```
#include "1.h"
...
void funcTest(testT **t, int *size, ..){
    createMem(t,*size); /* void createMem(testT **t, int size); */
    t[0]->a = 0;
    /* ... more code ... */
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it is this way, take a look: http://pastebin.com/ZbudbbVE
But still, the error is here >_<

Comment: @Shuryon: no, it's not this way: the definition of `positionLeaf` in your code is in matriz.c, not matriz.h!

Comment: Uhn.. The program compiles this way but get `segmentation fault` at `matriz[i]->row` when running the programm.
_At_ the `for` loop

Comment: @Shuryon: it doesn't compile at my side. I pasted the log [here](http://pastebin.com/P6hsAhx7).

Comment: @Shuryon: or you mean that it compiles my way? Could you please paste the code which segfaults?

Answer (score 0):

> But, when running the compiled program, exactly where the error occurs is the place of t[0]->a.

The pointer to the allocated memory is actually in `*t`, not `t` (as seen from your `createMatrix` code at Pastebin), so you should really be doing:

```
(*t)[0].a
```

and similarly in your `for` loop:

```
(*matriz)[i].row
```

Comment: uhn.. another error appeared doing it:  `error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct positionLeaf’`

Comment: @Shuryon: Well you're mixing up two different kinds of errors. My answer was about run-time errors, what you're getting is a compile-time error (which others have discussed).