# Where should be the definition of a struct be declared in C? .c or .h?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

When implementing an ADT in C, I always thought that the definition of the `struct` should be in the `.c` file so that it was private. And in the `typedef` should be placed in the `.h` file so that other modules could use the ADT but could not modify its attributes directly.
I recently ran into a problem and I had to move the struct to the `.h`. I also found an answer [Error: In C, got the error "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type" in a struct pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275501/error-in-c-got-the-error-dereferencing-pointer-to-incomplete-type-in-a-struc) where it is said that the `struct` should be defined in `.c` file. Is this true? If it is, what is the reason?

Comment: What is your question exactly?  If the struct definition is needed from multiple .c files then it should go in the header, otherwise it doesn't have to.

Comment: @M.M It is only needed in one .c file. My question is if there is one option that is considered a good practice and not the other, and if it that is the case why.

Comment: That's a matter of opinion really.Generally speaking it's good practice to not put something in a header if it is not required to be used elsewhere

Comment: The structure definition for an ADT should usually be in the source (`.c`) file that defines the support functions, and only a declaration of the type should exist in the header (`.h`) file. However, that means you cannot allocate instances of the structure outside the source file defining the ADT. You can only define pointers to the ADT outside. If you had to move the definition from source to header, that means that something was not using a pointer that should have been using a pointer. Go back and fix the broken code, and move the structure definition back into the source file for the ADT.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I found my mistake, I was trying to allocate and array to the ADT and then accessing it with an index like myADT[3]. I changed to array of pointers and everything is good now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I noted in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47614952/where-sould-be-the-definition-of-a-struct-be-declared-in-c-c-or-h#comment82188574_47614952):

The structure definition for an ADT should usually be in the source (`.c`) file that defines the support functions, and only a declaration of the type should exist in the header (`.h`) file.

However, that means you cannot allocate instances of the structure outside the source file defining the ADT. You can only define pointers to the ADT outside.

If you had to move the definition from source to header, that means that something was not using a pointer that should have been using a pointer. Go back and fix the broken code, and move the structure definition back into the source file for the ADT.

And, confirming what [Nevado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6193510/nevado) notes in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47614952/where-sould-be-the-definition-of-a-struct-be-declared-in-c-c-or-h#comment82188597_47614952), it also means you cannot have an array of the ADT; you can have arrays of pointers to the ADT, but not arrays of the ADT itself.

Note that it is perfectly legitimate to expose the structure if that's what you wish, or need, to do.  That then allows you to create variables of the data type, or arrays of them, or to embed the type (rather than a pointer to the type) in other structures, etc.  You lose some control; the programmer writing the code that uses the structure can see the details and could access (read or modify) the structure elements directly.  Cautious programmers won't do that unnecessarily, but it opens up possibilities precluded by the strict ADT idiom — at the risk of mistakes being made.